# Group Width and Height in R so it can be plotted in a barchart

Tags: r

I have a data frame that contains over 2000 rows of Width and Heights. When I try to plot them there are no room for all data, so I was thinking that I can group the Width and Height into groups, then count how many exists in each group and plot that.

I was thinking the following groups (but I am not sure if this is the best groups):

- groups <- c("Below 200x200", "200x200", "720x480", "720x576 ", "128x720",
  "1920x1080 ", "3840×2160", "Over 3840x2160")

After some googling I've seen that [tidyverse](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/grouping.html) has grouping. Can it be used? I tried some code from it but it doesn't work

```
starwars %>%
  group_by(df = cut(df$Width, breaks=groups)) %>%
  tally()
```

My code:

```
# Library
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

# 1. Read data
df = read.csv2(text = "ID;Width;Height
1;255;298
2;600;900
3;333;459
4;333;459
5;800;574
6;512;768
7;768;1024
8;768;1024
9;800;574
10;512;768
11;640;1136
12;1200;1600
13;255;298
14;600;900
15;600;900
16;255;298
17;512;768
18;600;900
19;255;298
20;600;900
21;768;1024
22;255;298
23;640;1136
24;640;1136
25;333;459
26;255;340
27;1200;1600
28;640;1136
29;255;298
30;255;298")

# Groups
groups <- c("0x0", "200x200", "720x480", "720x576 ", "128x720", "1920x1080 ", "3840×2160", Inf)

starwars %>%
  group_by(df = cut(df$Width, breaks=groups)) %>%
  tally()


# Plot bar chart
df %>% 
  mutate(dimensions = paste(Width, "x ", Height)) %>% 
  add_count(dimensions, name = "Freq") %>%
  arrange(Width, Height) %>% 
  mutate(labelpos = Freq + 0.2) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_inorder(dimensions) %>% fct_rev())) + 
  geom_bar() +
  coord_flip() + 
  labs(x="Dimensions", 
       y="Frequency") +
  theme_classic() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(Freq), y = labelpos), size=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I think you might need to manually allocate each `groups` category to each unique value of your `dimension` column.

Comment: How can I do this? By going trough all in a for loop and use if, elseif, else?

Comment: Yes or with an auxilary table